# Swift - How to save json files in the app prior to installation

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift

I'm pretty new to iOS, so I don't know the best solution for my problem: I use an API to get the data I show in my app (send request and get json files using Alamofire). My problem is that I can't rely on this API to always respond (the API creators know about this problem). So I was thinking of saving all the json files (several tens) I need in my app. Is this the best practice? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: You can certainly add content files to your project and read them if you can't connect to the end points. The files can be added to the project and selected as "Copy Bundle Resources"

Comment: Sounds like what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to bundle your app with those plists. It will be available to you on first ever app launch but would increase the app size as well(actually depends on individual plist size).

The plist needs to be copied to Bundle resources. Just add them in your workspace/project.

This way these plists are going to be bundled with your application like your .storyboard,.xib files and images. Also, as these can be read directly from your ipa, don't keep any secret data in these plists

[image]

After that to be sure just check the Target->BuildPhases-> Copy Bundle Resources. Your file should be listed there.
[image]

To read data from bundled plist (Swift 3):

```
if let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "fileName", withExtension: "plist"),
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileUrl) {
            if let result = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) {
                print(result) // result is of type Any here, and needs to be converted to appropriate type(depends on plist root)
            }
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like what I need. I'm new, so can you please elaborate?

Comment: These plists are bundled with your application like your .storyboard,.xib files, images. Also, as these can be read directly from your ipa, don't keep any secret data in these plists.

Answer (score 0):

Let me restate the problem and tell me if I understood correctly. Your app relies on making calls to the server to fetch data, and the server does not always respond. You are thinking of when the hits to the server are successful, you would like to save the data you fetch to be able to use them, when the server fails.

If that is the case, doing this depends on your app. If your application relies on showing live content to the user, then showing old content is useless then saving the data is useless; however, if the content you are presenting the the user is going to be almost the same or doesn't matter if much hasn't changed from this data, then it is best to save this data and show them to the user "as offline mode".

How to save this data? There are several methods in iOS to save content. One is saving your Objects in NSUserDefaults which is not very commended. The other two ways is saving in SQLLite or CoreData. You could look up more in the documentation or read articles on how to do this. I like saving in SQLLite the most its my personal preference. You should read on all three and see what best meets your needs.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. Since I cannot rely on the server response, I would like to add the json files to the app. When the user installs the app, I can stay offline and still see the data. And yes, the data is not not changing that much, so it's ok.